# indent ruby code on the fly in emacs

Tags: ruby, emacs

How to make Emacs automatically reindent Ruby code on the fly?

for example, with this in Emacs,

```
def hello
  puts "hello"
  en
```

After I type 'd', I want it to turn into this,

```
def hello
  puts "hello"
end
```

This is the default in Vim, but how can I achieve that in Emacs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ruby-electric` is old news. Emacs 24 has a built-in minor mode called `electric-indent-mode` that automatically inserts newlines after some chars and you can of course remap the `RETURN` key to `newline-and-indent` (it's mapped only to indent by default). In Emacs 24 you can get matching delims with `electric-pairs-mode` and `ruby-end` mode will insert automatically `end` for you when needed. You can have a look at the [prelude-ruby.el](https://github.com/bbatsov/prelude-modules/blob/master/prelude-ruby.el) for more details.

Comment: `electric-indent-mode` is nice, now I bind `RET` to `comment-indent-new-line`. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you add [ruby-electric](https://github.com/qoobaa/ruby-electric) (also part of [Rinari](http://rinari.rubyforge.org/)) you get the following:

- Correctly indented "end" when you write "class", "def", "module" etc.
- Matching delimiters when you type the opening one.

If you don't want to add extra modes, the `end` will be indented correctly once you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Or you press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to re-indent the current line.

Comment: Thanks for your tips, but is it possible to write an elisp function to make it do the indentation work on the fly?

Comment: How is this answer not on the fly?  Did you even try it?

Answer (score 0):

Try [Auto-indent-mode](https://github.com/mlf176f2/auto-indent-mode.el)!

1. Return automatically indents the code appropriately (if enabled)
2. Pasting/Yanking indents the appropriately
3. Killing line will take off unneeded spaces (if enabled)
4. On visit file, indent appropriately, but DONT SAVE. (Pretend like nothing happened, if enabled)
5. On save, optionally unttabify, remove trailing white-spaces, and definitely indent the file (if enabled).

Answer (score 0):

It won't work because Ruby doesn't know whether you want to type "end" of any variables started with "end". So typing `Tab` to re-indent it is necessary. And the following configuration works well for me.

```
; auto indent                                                                                                                                                                                                       
(define-key global-map (kbd "RET") 'newline-and-indent)
(add-hook 'ruby-mode-hook (lambda () (local-set-key "\r" 'newline-and-indent)))
```