# Ruby on Emacs Package Installation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, emacs, ruby-mode

In reference to [indent ruby code on the fly in emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11305600/indent-ruby-code-on-the-fly-in-emacs), how do I make a minor mode fire up automatically after a major mode is entered?

Basically, when I open a Ruby file (which opens in `ruby-mode`), I would like `electric-indent-mode` to start up automatically.

Also, I tried installing `ruby-end` but it is not working. I copied the `ruby-end.rb` into `~/.emacs.d` and added the following into `init.el`:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "ruby-end")
(require 'ruby-end)
```

I also `ruby-end.pl` and I get the same error. Here is the result of `--debug-init`'s error:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (file-error "Cannot open load file" "ruby-end")
2   require(ruby-end)
3   eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/Users/nayef/.emacs.d/init.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 1392
4   load-with-code-conversion("/Users/nayef/.emacs.d/init.el" "/Users/nayef/.emacs.d/init.el" t t)
5   load("/Users/nayef/.emacs.d/init" t t)
6   #[0 "^H\205\262^@     \306=\203^Q^@\307^H\310Q\202;^@ \311=\204^^^@\307^H\312Q\202;^@\313\307\314\315#\203*^@\316\202;^@\313\307\314\317#\203:^@\320\nB^R$
7   command-line()
8   normal-top-level()
```

Any ideas? Does anyone have pointers on Ruby on Rails development in Emacs? I use command-line based text Emacs 24.2.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`electric-indent-mode` is a global minor mode (i.e. it applies to all buffers in all modes), so just enable it once in your .emacs, no need to play around with hooks.

Comment: Wouldn't it mess around the indentation in other languages? Also, how would I make it globally enabled? I tried `setq` that didn't work.

Comment: Like every minor mode, you can use `(electric-indent-mode 1)` in your `.emacs` to enable it.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the specific problem you're having here, `load-path` should contain directories, not file paths. So, try this:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d"))
(require 'ruby-end)
```

By the way, I still prefer the older `ruby-electric`.